# How to manage users and access to the different sites in intranet from a main server?

Tags: php, openid, intranet

I have more than four sites on my intranet. Now what i want to do is to manage all these sites from the main site. I need to manage that main site which can give access to the users to go to these sites and do the thing that can be done by logging to the individual sites.

I read about OpenID on this link http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581

Now I want to know that if I can manage this using OpenID or is there any other way to do.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you're wanting. Are you wanting to run numerous sites from a single code base, with unique login mechanisms for each site?

I achieved a similar thing recently. I had a website that was available in different languages, and each language version had its own domain, parked on a single web server. My `index.php` picked up the domain the code was being accessed from and checked to see if there was a valid login for that particular domain.

This is using something as simple as a cookie or session, as both work on a per-domain basis. Therefore, if I logged on at `example.com` but then went to `example.es`, I would be prompted to log in to `example.es` because I logged on in what was a different domain.

Hope this logic helps you out.